# Assign indices to a range of values

Tags: c#

I have a lot of particles on the screen that draw a certain object. In order to make a cool gradient effect, I have the following line:

```cs
float factor = (i - 0.0f) / (positions.Count - 0.0f);
```

This scales it between 1 and 0 to change the intensity of the color. Now this is rendered useless because the particles will be on on top of each other and so they'll look like full colors. I tried to finetune by doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Color color = Color.Red * 0.9f; /* factor going down in increments of 0.1f /
}
```

So that it looks like:

```
(color * incrementalFactor) * factor
```

Now because it gets repetitive to copy and paste this over and over again, I want to create a function that looks like this:

```
    Color[] colorTable = new Color[] {
        Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green
    };

    Color getColor(int i, int max)
    {
        int maxIndices = max / colorTable.Length; // the upper bound for each color
        /* Somehow get a color here */
    }
```

My issue is I do not know how to scale a value down to be an index to the colorTable dynamically based on a given index i, and a given max (i.e., positions.Count)

In other words, i needs to be 0 if below maxIndices, 1 if greater than that, but below maxIndices * 2, etc. up to the max value. How do I do this?

**EDIT**

Rephrasing the equation for clarity:

I have a function that takes two inputs: a given i, and a given max. The i always less than max.

Inside the function I get the step by dividing the max by a constant (let's say, 3). The function should return a value from 0 to this constant depending on the value of i relative to the step.

For example:
If the max was 1000

```
f(200, 1000) = 0
f(400, 1000) = 1
f(600, 1000) = 2
f(800, 1000) = 3
```

In other words,

```
step = 1000 / 3
if (i < step) return 0
if (i >= step && i < step * 2) return 1
```

The idea is to write a function to do this based on an arbitrary input.

Comment: What happens if you set all the Alpha's to some value around 30%-50%?

Comment: In  `Color color = Color.Red * 0.9f;` I don't see the loop variable being used

Comment: No, it's supposed to decrease by 0.1f every 1000 (or whatever step it is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see; according to the revised question this should work:

```
private int step = 3;
int StepDivider (int value, int maximum) {
  return value / (maximum / step);
}
```